# How to open different activity for each CardView in android?

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to open different Activity for different cards in CardView but I am only able to open the same activity for all the cards.
I am attaching my RVAdapter code below. Please help.

```
public class RVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVAdapter.PersonViewHolder>{
List<person> persons;
public static class PersonViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    CardView cv;
    TextView tv1,tv2;
    PersonViewHolder(View itemView){
        super(itemView);
        cv=(CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
        tv1=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tx1);
        tv2=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tx2);
        cv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override public void onClick(View v){
                cv.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(cv.getContext(), second.class));
            }

        });

    }
}
RVAdapter(List<person> persons){
    this.persons=persons;
}
@Override
public int getItemCount()
{
    return persons.size();
}
@Override
public PersonViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup,int i){
    View v= LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_scroll_activity,viewGroup,false);
    PersonViewHolder pvh=new PersonViewHolder(v);
    return pvh;
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(PersonViewHolder holder, int i) {
    holder.tv1.setText(persons.get(i).name);
    holder.tv2.setText(persons.get(i).branch);

}
@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView rcv)

{
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(rcv);
}
```

}

Comment: also In the onBindViewHolder, set the on click listener for the CardView rather than the ViewHolder constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've effectively only set one click listener.

You will want to set a click listener on each element in your list.

Inside your `onBindViewHolder` write something like this:

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override public void onClick(View v){
        v.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(v.getContext(), second.class));
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding of your question is correct, if there are three different card view, you have three different activities, each for every card view. To do that, you have to identify the card view using the position and then set click listener to associated activity for that particular cardview in `onBindViewHolder`

```
Intent intent;
if(i == 0)
    intent = new Intent(context, Class1.class);
else if(i == 1)
    intent = new Intent(context, Class2.class);
else
    intent = new Intent(context, Class3.class);

holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override public void onClick(View v){
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **OnClick Listener** implementation for **onBindViewHolder**.

Following gives a simple example with Toast for *showing which Card was selected* :
(inside onBindViewHolder)

```
holder.cv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
    {
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Pos : " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();            
    }
});
```

Just modify the onClick to call your activity.